# Python regex returning one group instead of two. What am I missing here?

Tags: python, regex

Let's say that I have a variable that can either be in the format of:

```
[+] Software in use: Calculator
```

or, in some cases, the software version number is shown:

```
[+] Software in use: Calculator - v2.3
```

I am attempting to capture 1) the software name, and 2) if provided, the version number.

Here's what I have so far:

```
line = '[+] Software in use: Calculator - v2.3'
searchObj = re.search('\[\+\] Software in use: (.+)( - v(\d+.\d+))?', line)
```

`searchObj.group(1)` returns the entire "Calculator - v2.3" Why is regex not splitting them up into groups? `searchObj.group(2)`, `searchObj.group(3)` does not exist. I thought that parenthesis signified a capture group. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Change `.+` to `.+?`, or just split the string without a regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
line = '[+] Software in use: Calculator - v2.3'
searchObj = re.search(r'\[\+\] Software in use: (.+?)(?:( - v(\d+.\d+))|$)', line)

                                                  ^^
```

Make it non greedy.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eB8xU8/10

or

```
\[\+\] Software in use: (.+?)( - v(\d+.\d+))?\b
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eB8xU8/11

Comment: Shouldn't also `?` at the end of regex be removed?

Comment: @soon no it need not be

Comment: Oh, yes, missed the input case without version block

Answer (score 3):

So the regex characters `+`, and `*` are greedy. This means they match as much as possible, before attempting future matches.

In your regex you use `(.+)( - v(\d+.\d+))?`. The second capture group will match as little as possible, because the `?` makes it lazy (matches as little as possible). Combining this with the prior group being greedy means that the second group will never match anything.

Basically, just sticking in a `?`, the following should fix it

```
(.+)?( - v(\d+.\d+))?
```

I hope my explanation makes sense